# Assigning events to a VCL control created dynamically at runtime (2)

Tags: c++builder, vcl

This is related to [Assigning events to a VCL control created dynamically at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49040803/).

I used the above listed/reference post to solve a problem that I had with some code.  Thank you for providing that example.  I found it very useful, and implemented the "alternative" way that it provided as I was unable to make the first way work.

I am using C++Builder 10.x from Embarcadero.  I just updated to C++Builder 10.3.  This new update is now throwing a warning:

> [bcc32c Warning] LogitToMemo.cpp(196): implicit conversion between pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object is a Microsoft extension

The line it is throwing on is:

```
Method.Code = &LogLevelComboBoxOnChange;
```

I am not sure how to "fix" this.

The code is in support of a logging function to a memo field, where the page for the logging memo has a `TComboBox` to select the logging level/verbosity.

The `TComboBox` is external to the logging function, as it is on the user's form.  I want the `TComboBox::OnChange` event to call my `LogLevelComboBoxOnChange` function, which adjusts the logging level based on the `TComboBox` item/entry selected.

Supporting code around this includes.

Function declaration - `TComboBox::OnChange` Event Function

```
void __fastcall LogLevelComboBoxOnChange(void *pThis, TObject *Sender);
```

Function Declaration - Logging start up where the `TMemo` field to log to & the `TComboBox` are provided

```
int LogStartWithComboBox(TMemo *LogIt_MemoField, TComboBox *AppLogLevelComboBox, int iThreshold, AnsiString &asFieldTitles);
```

This is the function that assigns the `OnChange` function to the `TComboBox` object on the user's logging form.

```
int LogStartWithComboBox(TMemo *LogIt_MemoField, TComboBox *AppLogLevelComboBox, int iThreshold, AnsiString &asFieldTitles)
{
  static TMethod Method;

  //
  //  Set-Up CombBox and OnChange Event
  //  - Save ComboBox pointer
  //  - Assign List of Log Levels
  //  - Assign/Set-Up OnChange Function
  //
  LogLevelComboBox = AppLogLevelComboBox;

  AppLogLevelComboBox->Items->Text =
    "Off\n"
    "All Messages\n"
    "Verbose\n"
    "Trace\n"
    "Informational\n"
    "Warning\n"
    "Error\n"
    "Severe\n"
    "Fatal";

  AppLogLevelComboBox->ItemIndex = iThreshold + 1;

  //
  //  Set-Up - On Change Function for "external" Log Level Combo-Box
  //
  Method.Data = NULL; // passed to the pThis parameter, can be whatever you want

  // 
  //  The Following line generates the warning
  //    [bcc32c Warning] LogitToMemo.cpp(196): implicit conversion between pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object is a Microsoft extension
  //
  Method.Code = &LogLevelComboBoxOnChange;

  LogLevelComboBox->OnChange = reinterpret_cast<TNotifyEvent&>(Method);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*implemented the "alternative" way that it provided as I was unable to make the first way work*" - why not?  What problem did you have with the "first" way exactly?  Both ways work just fine when used properly.

Comment: You don't need to declare the `TMethod` variable as `static`, as there is no need to preserve it once the `OnChange` event has been assigned.  And why are you using (and ignoring) `AnsiString` in a Unicode environment? You should be using `String` (or `UnicodeString` directly) instead. I assume you meant to use `AppLogLevelComboBox->Items->Text = asFieldTitles;` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You are using C++Builder's CLang-based C++ compiler.  The "implicit conversion" warning you are seeing is a CLang issue that has cropped up during the past few years in multiple toolchains that use CLang, not just in C++Builder.  This issue does not affect C++Builder's "classic" (non-CLang) compiler.

`&LogLevelComboBoxOnChange` creates a pointer-to-function, which CLang does not like to implicitly convert to `void*` (which is what the `TMethod::Code` field is declared as) unless Clang is put into a Microsoft compatibility mode.

Possible solutions are to either:

- type-cast the pointer explicitly:

  (**UPDATE:** apparently CLang [doesn't like `static_cast`ing](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wmicrosoft-cast) a pointer-to-function to `void*`, either!)
  <s>Method.Code = static_cast<void*>(&LogLevelComboBoxOnChange);</s>

  ```
  Method.Code = reinterpret_cast<void*>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&LogLevelComboBoxOnChange));
  ```
- enable the `-Wmicrosoft-cast` flag in the CLang compiler settings.
- disable the warning in your code by using `#pragma` statements around the assignment to `Method.Code`:

  ```
  #pragma clang diagnostic push
  #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wmicrosoft-cast"

  Method.Code = &LogLevelComboBoxOnChange;

  #pragma clang diagnostic pop
  ```
- use a `union` (though, I'm sure some people will argue that this probably violates Strict Aliasing rules, but if it works...):

  ```
  union {
      void (__fastcall *func)(void*, TObject*);
      void *ptr;
  } u;
  u.func = &LogLevelComboBoxOnChange;
  Method.Code = u.ptr;
  ```

Comment: Remy,

Thank you for your quick reply.

I changed to the type-cast pointer explicitly as you suggested

    Method.Code = static_cast<void*>(&LogLevelComboBoxOnChange);

I received the following waring still

[bcc32c Warning] LogitToMemo.cpp(197): implicit conversion between pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object is a Microsoft extension

I would like to understand and do the "right way" fix this instead of ignoring the warning.  That is if it is possible.

In response to your other comments.

-  I have now removed the static on the declaration of "Method"

Comment: In response to your other comments.

-  I have now removed the static on the declaration of "Method"

-  The asFieldTitles is a returned string to provide the column titles for above the logging TMemo field

-  I am still using AnsiStrings from some of my older/legacy code.  

-  I have converted some of my older/legacy code, as I need it in new code, where I can.  There seem to be in some instances where I have not found some of the conversion and string handling capabilities that are available for AnsiStrings in the UnicodeStrings.

Comment: @Mike upon further review, I would have expected [a different warning](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wmicrosoft-cast) on the `static_cast`: "*static_cast between pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object is a Microsoft extension*". Apparently CLang simply doesn't like assigning a pointer-to-function to a `void*`. So, you will just have to disable the warning (and it is just a warning in your case, not an error). Or try `reinterpret_cast` instead of `static_cast`: `Method.Code = reinterpret_cast<void*>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&LogLevelComboBoxOnChange));`

Comment: @Mike or, maybe try using a `union` to avoid type-casting: `union { void (__fastcall *func)(void*, TObject*); void *ptr; } u; u.func = &LogLevelComboBoxOnChange; Method.Code = u.ptr;` Though some people will probably argue that this violates Strict Aliasing rules, but if it works...